# Method of moments estimate: custom distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-problem

> Find the maximum likelihood estimation of $\mu$ and the population mean given a $n$-sized sample of a population with distribution function:
>
> $$\begin{aligned}f(x)=\frac1p, \quad
> 0 < x < p
> \end{aligned}$$
>
> Estimate $p$ with the method of moments

I really don't know where to start from here.
I understand
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k = E\left(x\right)$$

But I don't know what is the value of $E\left(x\right)$ of my distribution function.
Thanks in advance.